# Sending information through Bluetooth 4.0 (LE) with Tinyduino

Tags: c++

My task is to measure distances quite rapidly and send the data to a computer. I need to do it with the following equipment:

- [Tinyduino Processor board](https://tiny-circuits.com/shop/tinyduino-processor-board/)
- [Tinyduino Bluetooth LE shield](https://tiny-circuits.com/shop/tinyshield-bluetooth-le/https://tiny-circuits.com/shop/tinyshield-bluetooth-le/)
- Tinyduino Cell Battery
- [Ping))) Ultrasonic Distance Sensor](http://www.parallax.com/product/28015?SortField=ProductName,ProductName)

**Distance**

I have found the distance already and it is right now stored in an int.

**Bluetooth**

For the bluetooth I am using the [BGLib](https://github.com/jrowberg/bglib/tree/master/Arduino)

As mentioned above the distance is measured many times rapidly so I want to either transfer the data quickly or store the data somehow until measurement is done (after approximate 3 seconds). I have established connection to a connection already (GAP discoverabled undirected connectable). 
Because I am using the Tinyduino Bluetooth LE shield, it already have a firmware that I cannot change. It consists of 2 charateristics: TX and RX. My problem is now I do not understand how to send the specific data to computer.

*Do I need to write a response to a command by the computer, or do I send a command with the `sendCommand` function, or even a third?*

And just another thing; is it better to store the data and wait till the measurement is over or should I try to transfer it while I measure it.

(if there are some comments you would like to know what means, just write because they are Danish)

My current code:

```
#include <BGLib.h>
#include <BGLibConfig.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "BGLib.h"

//Uncomment denne linje for at debugge via USB
//#define DEBUG

//BLE er forkortelse for Bluetooth Low Energy

// ================================================================
// BLE FORBINDELSESTILSTAND 
// ================================================================

// BLE TILSTANDSDEFINITONER
#define BLE_STATE_STANDBY           0
#define BLE_STATE_SCANNING          1
#define BLE_STATE_ADVERTISING       2
#define BLE_STATE_CONNECTING        3
#define BLE_STATE_CONNECTED_MASTER  4
#define BLE_STATE_CONNECTED_SLAVE   5

// BLE state/link status
uint8_t ble_state = BLE_STATE_STANDBY;
uint8_t ble_encrypted = 0;  // 0 = not encrypted, otherwise = encrypted
uint8_t ble_bonding = 0xFF; // 0xFF = no bonding, otherwise = bonding handle

// ================================================================
// HARDWARE FORBINDELSE OG GATT STRUKTUR SETUP
// ================================================================

#define LED_PIN 13  // Status LED-pin
#define PING_PIN 11  // Ping pin til at ultralydssensor

#define GATT_HANDLE_C_RX_DATA   17  // 0x11, supports "write" operation
#define GATT_HANDLE_C_TX_DATA   20  // 0x14, supports "read" and "indicate" operations

// Brug softwareSerial på pins D3/D4 for RX/TX (Arduino side)
SoftwareSerial bleSerialPort(3, 4);

// Opret BGLib objekt:
//  - use SoftwareSerial port for module comms
//  - use nothing for passthrough comms (0 = null pointer)
//  - enable packet mode on API protocol since flow control is unavailable
BGLib ble112((HardwareSerial *)&bleSerialPort, 0, 1);

#define BGAPI_GET_RESPONSE(v, dType) dType *v = (dType *)ble112.getLastRXPayload()



// ================================================================
// ARDUINO SETUP OG LOOP FUNKTIONER
// ================================================================

// Kør under startup
void setup() {
    // Klargør status LED
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);

    // BGLib lyttere
    ble112.ble_evt_system_boot = my_ble_evt_system_boot;
    ble112.ble_evt_connection_status = my_ble_evt_connection_status;
    ble112.ble_evt_connection_disconnected = my_ble_evt_connection_disconnect;
    //ble112.ble_evt_attributes_value = my_ble_evt_attributes_value;

    // Åben Arduino USB serial, hvis vi skal debugge
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.begin(38400);
    #endif

    // Åben BLE software serial port
    bleSerialPort.begin(38400);

    my_ble_evt_system_boot( NULL);
}

// Main loop
void loop() {
    //Få afstand i microsekunder
    int *x = ping();

    // Bliv ved med at spørge efter ny data hos BLE
    ble112.checkActivity();

    // Få Arduino LED at blinke baseret på tilstand:
    //  - konstant = STANDBY
    //  - 1 puls per sekund = ADVERTISING
    //  - 2 puls per sekund = CONNECTED_SLAVE
    //  - 3 puls per sekund = CONNECTED_SLAVE med kryptering
    uint16_t slice = millis() % 1000;
    if (ble_state == BLE_STATE_STANDBY) {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    } else if (ble_state == BLE_STATE_ADVERTISING) {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, slice < 100); 
    } else if (ble_state == BLE_STATE_CONNECTED_SLAVE) {
        if (!ble_encrypted) {
            digitalWrite(LED_PIN, slice < 100 || (slice > 200 && slice < 300));
        } else {
            digitalWrite(LED_PIN, slice < 100 || (slice > 200 && slice < 300) || (slice > 400 && slice < 500));
        }
    }
}

int *ping()
{
    //Variabler til at lagre målte værdier
    int microseconds, cm;

    //Send ping, som bagefter skal læses
    pinMode(PING_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(PING_PIN, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(PING_PIN, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(PING_PIN, LOW);

    //Aflæs tiden
    pinMode(PING_PIN, INPUT);
    microseconds = pulseIn(PING_PIN, HIGH);

    //Konverter mikrosekunder til cm. Det går 29 microsekunder pr centimeter. 
    //Halver afstand, fordi vi vil ikke have afstanden både frem og tilbage, men derimod kun den ene vej.
    cm = microseconds / 29 / 2;

    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print(cm, DEC);
    #endif

    return &cm;
}

// ================================================================
// APPLICATION HÆNDELSES FUNKTIONER
// ================================================================

void my_ble_evt_system_boot(const ble_msg_system_boot_evt_t *msg) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print("###\tsystem_boot: { ");
        Serial.print("major: "); Serial.print(msg -> major, HEX);
        Serial.print(", minor: "); Serial.print(msg -> minor, HEX);
        Serial.print(", patch: "); Serial.print(msg -> patch, HEX);
        Serial.print(", build: "); Serial.print(msg -> build, HEX);
        Serial.print(", ll_version: "); Serial.print(msg -> ll_version, HEX);
        Serial.print(", protocol_version: "); Serial.print(msg -> protocol_version, HEX);
        Serial.print(", hw: "); Serial.print(msg -> hw, HEX);
        Serial.println(" }");
    #endif

    // SYSTEM BOOT betyder at systemet er på standby
    //ble_state = BLE_STATE_STANDBY;
    // ^^^ Spring over fordi vi alligevel skifter til advertising nedenunder

    // Sæt advertisement interval to 200-300ms. Brug alle advertisement kanaler
    // (NOTE: min/max parametere er i 625 microsekunder)
    ble112.ble_cmd_gap_set_adv_parameters(320, 480, 7);
    while (ble112.checkActivity(1000));

    // USE THE FOLLOWING TO LET THE BLE STACK HANDLE YOUR ADVERTISEMENT PACKETS
    // ========================================================================
    // start advertising general discoverable / undirected connectable
    ble112.ble_cmd_gap_set_mode(BGLIB_GAP_GENERAL_DISCOVERABLE, BGLIB_GAP_UNDIRECTED_CONNECTABLE);
    while (ble112.checkActivity(1000));

    // set state to ADVERTISING
    ble_state = BLE_STATE_ADVERTISING;
}

void my_ble_evt_connection_status(const ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t *msg) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print("###\tconnection_status: { ");
        Serial.print("connection: "); Serial.print(msg -> connection, HEX);
        Serial.print(", flags: "); Serial.print(msg -> flags, HEX);
        Serial.print(", address: ");
        // this is a "bd_addr" data type, which is a 6-byte uint8_t array
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (msg -> address.addr[i] < 16) Serial.write('0');
            Serial.print(msg -> address.addr[i], HEX);
        }
        Serial.print(", address_type: "); Serial.print(msg -> address_type, HEX);
        Serial.print(", conn_interval: "); Serial.print(msg -> conn_interval, HEX);
        Serial.print(", timeout: "); Serial.print(msg -> timeout, HEX);
        Serial.print(", latency: "); Serial.print(msg -> latency, HEX);
        Serial.print(", bonding: "); Serial.print(msg -> bonding, HEX);
        Serial.println(" }");
    #endif

    // "flags" bit description:
    //  - bit 0: connection_connected
    //           Indicates the connection exists to a remote device.
    //  - bit 1: connection_encrypted
    //           Indicates the connection is encrypted.
    //  - bit 2: connection_completed
    //           Indicates that a new connection has been created.
    //  - bit 3; connection_parameters_change
    //           Indicates that connection parameters have changed, and is set
    //           when parameters change due to a link layer operation.

    // check for new connection established
    if ((msg -> flags & 0x05) == 0x05) {
        // track state change based on last known state, since we can connect two ways
        if (ble_state == BLE_STATE_ADVERTISING) {
            ble_state = BLE_STATE_CONNECTED_SLAVE;
        } else {
            ble_state = BLE_STATE_CONNECTED_MASTER;
        }
    }

    // update "encrypted" status
    ble_encrypted = msg -> flags & 0x02;

    // update "bonded" status
    ble_bonding = msg -> bonding;
}

void my_ble_evt_connection_disconnect(const struct ble_msg_connection_disconnected_evt_t *msg) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print("###\tconnection_disconnect: { ");
        Serial.print("connection: "); Serial.print(msg -> connection, HEX);
        Serial.print(", reason: "); Serial.print(msg -> reason, HEX);
        Serial.println(" }");
    #endif

    // set state to DISCONNECTED
    //ble_state = BLE_STATE_DISCONNECTED;
    // ^^^ skip above since we're going right back into advertising below

    // after disconnection, resume advertising as discoverable/connectable
    //ble112.ble_cmd_gap_set_mode(BGLIB_GAP_GENERAL_DISCOVERABLE, BGLIB_GAP_UNDIRECTED_CONNECTABLE);
    //while (ble112.checkActivity(1000));

    // after disconnection, resume advertising as discoverable/connectable (with user-defined advertisement data)
    ble112.ble_cmd_gap_set_mode(BGLIB_GAP_USER_DATA, BGLIB_GAP_UNDIRECTED_CONNECTABLE);
    while (ble112.checkActivity(1000));

    // set state to ADVERTISING
    ble_state = BLE_STATE_ADVERTISING;

    // clear "encrypted" and "bonding" info
    ble_encrypted = 0;
    ble_bonding = 0xFF;
}

/*void my_ble_evt_attributes_value(const struct ble_msg_attributes_value_evt_t *msg) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print("###\tattributes_value: { ");
        Serial.print("connection: "); Serial.print(msg -> connection, HEX);
        Serial.print(", reason: "); Serial.print(msg -> reason, HEX);
        Serial.print(", handle: "); Serial.print(msg -> handle, HEX);
        Serial.print(", offset: "); Serial.print(msg -> offset, HEX);
        Serial.print(", value_len: "); Serial.print(msg -> value.len, HEX);
        Serial.print(", value_data: ");
        // this is a "uint8array" data type, which is a length byte and a uint8_t* pointer
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < msg -> value.len; i++) {
            if (msg -> value.data[i] < 16) Serial.write('0');
            Serial.print(msg -> value.data[i], HEX);
        }
        Serial.println(" }");
    #endif

    // check for data written to "c_rx_data" handle
    if (msg -> handle == GATT_HANDLE_C_RX_DATA && msg -> value.len > 0) {
        // set ping 8, 9, and 10 to three lower-most bits of first byte of RX data
        // (nice for controlling RGB LED or something)
        digitalWrite(8, msg -> value.data[0] & 0x01);
        digitalWrite(9, msg -> value.data[0] & 0x02);
        digitalWrite(10, msg -> value.data[0] & 0x04);
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your code has a potentially big issue: it is very bad programming practice to declare a variable in a function (`cm` in `ping()`) and returns a pointer to that variable (`return &cm;`) as its value will be overridden by the first call to any function after the return (`ble112.checkActivity();` in your case). Just do `return cm;` in `ping()` instead.

Comment: Hello Highace2 have you made any headway with the tinyduino and the bluetooth Le Module? I am having a similar issue which I have posted about [here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/6643/tinyduino-bluetooth-le-to-android-or-iphone) please take a look I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @har I'm afraid not. The project was submitted with an alternative solution because neither my team nor my teacher (who is a low current engineer with 10 years of experience) could get that thing working. The library is just plain rubish to people with little understanding of bluetooth 4.0 protocol (where it should be rather clear).

Comment: Highace2 thank you for your response, if you don't mind me asking what the alternative solution to your problem was? Did you still use BLE? Thank you.

Comment: @har No, we did not. Our goal was to use an accelerometer inside a plastic bottle but ended up using a range finder on top of tube in which the plastic bottle flew. That was our solution.